# Require overwrite confirmation for one specific file in Inno Setup, install other files in directory unconditionally

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have a directory (`Configurationfiles`) containing 84 files. One of these files contains data that the user will modify (`UserData.json`). This file may or may not be there, but if it is I don't want to lose this data, and am trying to keep the install user friendly.

I am trying to modify an existing an install script that does all of the following:

1. If there are no files in the directory, copy all of them
2. If there are files overwrite all files except `UserData.json`
3. if `UserData.json` is missing copy default `UserData.json`
4. If `UserData.json` is present prompt user to overwrite `UserData.json`, if yes overwrite, if no don't

Currently all of the files are copied no matter what and I never get a prompt to overwrite. This is what I have so far:

```
#define ExcludeFiles "UserData.json"

Source: ..\..\PROV\4200701\BIN\*.*; Excludes: {#ExcludeFiles }; DestDir: {app}\BIN; \
  Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs skipifsourcedoesntexist;

Source: ..\..\PROV\4200701\BIN\Configurationfiles\UserData.json; \
  DestDir: {app}\BIN\Configurationfiles; 
  Flags: ignoreversion onlyifdoesntexist confirmoverwrite skipifsourcedoesntexist;
```

I think I have something set up incorrectly with the flags. But I am not sure. Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never get the confirmation, as the `onlyifdoesntexist` prevents the `confirmoverwrite` from ever taking any effect.

I do not think, that you are correct with *"all of the files are copied no matter"*. When I test your script, I get:

> 2020-09-26 16:51:21.625   -- File entry --
> 2020-09-26 16:51:21.626   Dest filename: C:\Users\pimpo\AppData\Local\My Program\BIN\Configurationfiles\UserData.json
> 2020-09-26 16:51:21.626   Time stamp of our file: 2020-09-26 16:49:30.000
> 2020-09-26 16:51:21.626   Dest file exists.
> 2020-09-26 16:51:21.626   **Skipping due to "onlyifdoesntexist" flag.**

---

If you remove the `onlyifdoesntexist`, your script should do what you want.

> 2020-09-26 16:57:41.066   -- File entry --
> 2020-09-26 16:57:41.067   Dest filename: C:\Users\pimpo\AppData\Local\My Program\BIN\Configurationfiles\UserData.json
> 2020-09-26 16:57:41.067   Time stamp of our file: 2020-09-26 16:49:30.000
> 2020-09-26 16:57:41.067   Dest file exists.
> 2020-09-26 16:57:41.067   Time stamp of existing file: 2020-09-26 16:49:30.000
> 2020-09-26 16:57:41.067   Message box (Yes/No):
> C:\Users\pimpo\AppData\Local\My Program\BIN\Configurationfiles\UserData.json
>
> **The file already exists.**
>
> **Would you like Setup to overwrite it?**
> 2020-09-26 16:57:43.055   User chose Yes.
> 2020-09-26 16:57:43.055   Installing the file.
> 2020-09-26 16:57:43.062   Successfully installed the file.

---

*You might want to remove the `ignoreversion` too, as it has no effect on `.json` files. It may confuse others. The `skipifsourcedoesntexist` is also questionable.*

Comment: Thank you, I removed the (onlyifdoesntexsist) flag and it is working correctly.